# How to use s3distcp for selecting date ranges?

Tags: amazon-s3, hive, amazon-emr, emr

I have logs that look like the below in s3 with a time stamp in the the name.  I want to use s3distcp to get data into EMR so I can use hive.

```
https://s3.amazonaws.com/mybucket/test/201305031003_0_ubuntu.gz
https://s3.amazonaws.com/mybucket/test/201305031004_0_ubuntu.gz
https://s3.amazonaws.com/mybucket/test/201305031005_0_ubuntu.gz
https://s3.amazonaws.com/mybucket/test/201305031006_0_ubuntu.gz
```

How do I use s3distcp to select a date range?  E.g. from 201303031003 to 201305031003?  That is a two month difference

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [--srcPattern s3distcp option](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/UsingEMR_s3distcp.html) to specify a regex to only select the months you want to copy over.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is use `--srcPrefixesFile` parameter to specify all objects that you want to be copied/moved.

This involves an additional step to generate this list, but is a safer way if you want to test it before to run your `s3distcp` step.